# FileProvider provider path cannot point to assets folder

Tags: android, excel, android-fileprovider

I have defined the provider in my manifest file as below:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

The provider_paths file has a files_path defined as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <files-path name="files" path="/"/>
    </paths>
```

I have an excel file in my Assets/Templates folder and I would like to get the uri of the excel file using FileProvider.getUriFromFile.

Please help me out here! Thanks.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: I think use ContentProvider for this